# Loop shaping error

Tags: control, control-system, boost, pid-controller

I have a plant transfer function (Gp) as shown,
[image]

The GCF is at 20 kHz, and my intended switching frequency is 20 kHz, so as a first step in shaping the loop gain I try to shift it to a new desired GCF at 3 kHz. Gp has an excess gain of 20.1 dB at 3 kHz, so compensator magnitude at 3 kHz should be -20.1 dB.

Next the phase of Gp at 3 kHz is 219 degrees, so if I want a Phase margin of 60 degrees, required phase boost from compensator is 39 + 60 ~= 100 degrees.

Now a double pole-zero pair type compensator can be used to provide boost > 90 deg. I choose my
f_peak = 3 kHz.
$$ f_{peak} = 3 kHz $$
\$ k = \tan\left( \dfrac{boost}{4} + \dfrac{\pi}{4} \right) \\ \$

\$ f_p = k.f_{peak} = 8242.4 Hz\$

\$ f_z = f_{peak}/k = 1090.9 Hz \$

Finally my compensator has a double pole-zero pair with an integrator at the origin.

However, no matter how I choose the integrator gain, I never seem to get positive gain margin, even if I get positive phase margin. How to choose the integrator's gain and where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you considered that you might need something other than a single integrator? (I haven't done any analysis so you might not, but it's worth considering.)

Comment: Greatest Common Factor = GCF???

Comment: @Andyaka Gain crossover frequency I mean, sorry!

Comment: I suspect you got mislead by the 360° point at 0 Hz displayed by Matlab. Add -360° to the whole curve and it will start at 0° (which is the same) but then the phase at which you determine the wanted boost will be -141° which makes better sense. You can't have a positive phase for the plant here. From this -141°, determine the boost and compute the pole and zero of the type 2.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thank you - I did calculate by subtracting 360 from the plot. 141 lag is 219 lead, so my required boost would be 39 + 60 = 99 deg. I substituted 100 in the calculation of k. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand how you get the needed phase boost. If you shoot for a phase margin of 70°, then the boost should be 70+141-90=121°. If you calculate backward, then you have the plant phase shift at -141°-270° (inverting op amp plus pole at the origin)+121° = -290°, away from -360° by 70° of PM. Place the double pole-zero pair accordingly. I use the k factor for type 2 only. For type 3, in which the boost is greater than 90°, I prefer manual poles-zeroes placement for better compensation.

Comment: I see the issue here: in your poles-zeroes placement, the value for the k factor method is \$f_c\$, the crossover frequency you want, not the resonating frequency you observe (you call it \$f_{peak}\$ but it is \$f_0\$). So you should write \$f_{p12}=kf_c\$ and \$f_{z12}=\frac{f_c}{k}\$. The crossover frequency should be selected 3-5 times away from \$f_0\$.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thank you for replying. So I followed your last comment, and the GCF is correct, but how do I calculate what the gain should be for the pole at the origin? This pole needs to be added to avoid steady state error, but when I calc. it as f_c * 10^(-gain/20) it doesn't give me the correct result.